# WebSocket - "drain"-event?

Tags: javascript, stream, websocket

Many node.js streams, including some WebSocket implementations, have the "drain"-event, wich notifies the program, that the queued data has been sent/written.

I wonder if it is possible to get this event also on the client side.

I'm creating the library "channel.js" at https://github.com/VanCoding/channel.js which needs this event to know when new data can be sent without queuing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [socket.io](http://socket.io/)?

Comment: @JohnnyLeung According to https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events there's no such event in socket.io. It would have been to bloated for my needs anyway. I'd like to stick just with plain, simple WebSockets.

Comment: did you try WebSocket-Node? https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node

Comment: @vinayr This seems to be an implementation for node.js. I need the drain-event in the browser implemention of WebSocket.